# How do I achieve a storage pool on my NAS?

Tags: windows, nas, storage, freenas

I'm about to get a NAS for my home, and I'm thinking about FreeNas as opposed to a commercial solution, but I'm open to the most convenient and smooth solution

The single most important thing I want is being able to add the disks in the nas to a storage pool and then have that pool mapped in e.g. Windows, as a single disk, like on Windows Home Server. Is this even possible? If so, how would it be done?

If I were to get a commercial solution, what would you recommend that has this feature? I'm thinking about a Synology ds1511+, would that work? I recall something about a storage pool setup with ISCSI on that NAS, but I have no idea as to how one would go about that.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an essential feature for any NAS device. For [FreeNAS](http://www.freenas.org/), the best way to achieve this is by using ZFS as the file system.

With ZFS, you add physical drives to a virtual device (a `vdev`), and pick the way the drives are combined (mirrored, aggregated, or RAID-Z). Then one or more `vdev`s are added to a storage pool, known as a `zpool`.

With a newly created `zpool`, you need to specify the file system mount point, and then create directories as needed. [Network shares](http://dailycupoftech.com/creating-windows-shares-on-freenas/) (e.g., SMB/CIFS shares) expose these directories to the other computers on the network.

This might sound a bit involved, but it can all be done from FreeNAS's web interface. I'd recommend getting comfortable with your setup of `vdevs` and `zpools` before committing data to the NAS. iSCSI can also be set up from the web interface. I don't have any experience with this, but [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/40641/is-iscsi-good-for-my-situation) has more info.

Version 8 of FreeNAS is a complete re-write of [version 0.7](http://wiki.freenas.org/). So, at the moment, version 0.7 still has more functionality.